# mysqli_result::fetch_all returning Null

Tags: php, mysqli, null

I have this rather strange problem with `fetch_all()` giving me null but the results do exist and I use the exact same code elsewhere (with different queries) and it works fine too. I've even tested the query with SQL directly and it works fine too. So I'm hoping somebody could help me to understand why this function seems to return null for this particular query. The entire code is as follows and the commented out `while loop` returns results too; it's literally just `fetch_all()` that isn't.

```
require_once 'config.php'; //connect info
 $mysqli="";
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo $mysqli->connect_error;
    return false;
}

$data = "";
$id=6;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE client_id=?");
if(false===$stmt)  die("prepare() failed: " . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
if(false===$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) die("bind_param() failed: " . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
if(false===$stmt->execute()) die("execute() failed: " . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    $data = json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    //{
    //  $data .= $row['comment'] . " " . $row['date'];
    //}
}
else
{
    echo 'no results';
}

var_dump($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)); //returns array(0) { }
var_dump($data); //returns bool(false)
```

The only possibility I can think of is that it's something to do with the database table structure but I wouldn't know why.

The `comments` table structure is as follows:

```
`comments` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Of course, `id` is primary, unique and auto incrementing.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) returned result set identifier by `mysqli_query()`

So instead of

```
if($result->num_rows>0)
```

You use

```
if($stmt->num_rows>0)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! You've saved me a world of pain =)